# TSQL - Insert Multiple datasets without join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I am working on and trying to think through this scenario.

I allow a user to pick multiple documents that have a `PK` of `ID`. They can then select multiple names from a list to assign to those documents.

I am trying to figure out how to say "Insert this list of people, for each one of these documents".

I tried creating a temp table for both data sets and then using a `crossjoin` but only one set is being inserted so I assume I am doing that wrong.

```
-- Create a temp tables to hold our data
DECLARE @documents AS TABLE(documentID INT)
DECLARE @users AS TABLE(UID VARCHAR(10), contactType VARCHAR(50))

-- Insert our documents
INSERT INTO @documents( documentID )
SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('docID[1]', 'INT')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data/documents/document') AS ParamValues(x1);


-- Insert our users
INSERT INTO @users( UID, contactType )
SELECT  ParamValues.x1.value('UID[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
        ParamValues.x1.value('contactType[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data/users/user') AS ParamValues(x1)


-- Do we user contact data to insert?
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @users)
BEGIN
    -- Insert our users
    INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentContacts ( documentID, UID, contactLevel )
    SELECT documentID,
           u.UID,
           u.contactType
    FROM   @documents
    CROSS JOIN @users AS u
END
```

The data being sent over is an XML string and those ID's are being put into temp tables.

Since the users and the documents don't have a `FK` with each other, how else could I join this data?

Example:

- Documents Temp Table - 22,33,44,55
- Users Temp Table - 1,2,3,4

Final result should insert a record into my table `dbo.DocumentContacts` as the following, for each document ID:

- (document 22, user 1)
- (document 22, user 2)
- (document 22, user 3)
- (document 22, user 4)
- (document 33, user 1)

.....

Comment: Seems right to me, have you tried to print out each temp table just to be sure that they have correct data?